# How to convert numbers to percentage for each measure in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data set something like this:

[image]

And I've visualized this data set like this:

[image]

But now, I want to convert the number to percentage. For instance, when name is A in the price_1 section, there are 1210 X type and 2095 Y type. Instead of showing this number, I would like to have 1210/1210+2095 in X, 2095/1210+2095 in Y.

How can I do this?

Comment: read about table calc in the online help

Answer (score 0):

You can click on Measure Values -> Quick Table Calculation -> Percent of total. Then you can modify the `Compute using` to make sure it's the percentage you want.